# Pandas, Using .loc on a cell from another row

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements, pandas-loc

I am looking to manipulate a large set of data based on a couple of conditionals. One is based on the same row whereas the other is based on a cell from a different row.

For example i have a df like this,where I have used

`df['true'] = df.loc[:,['max','value']].min(axis=1)` to add the 'true' column

```
max    value   true
0,00    3,00    0,00
0,00    4,00    0,00
0,00    4,00    0,00
0,00    2,00    0,00
3,00    3,00    3,00
3,00    1,00    1,00
3,00    4,00    3,00
3,00    1,00    1,00
3,00    4,00    3,00
3,00    0,00    0,00
```

But I would also like to add a condition to the column 'true' based on the value of a cell in 'max' two rows up. Like .loc I would like to check the entire dataframe for this condition with something like

```
df.loc[df['max'] - 2 = 0,'true'] = 0
```

and since pandas is very good at querying i don't want to write an if statement to iterate over the entire dataframe.

The output in this case would be:

```
max    value   true
0,00    3,00    0,00
0,00    4,00    0,00
0,00    4,00    0,00
0,00    2,00    0,00
3,00    3,00    **0,00**
3,00    1,00    **0,00**
3,00    4,00    3,00
3,00    1,00    1,00
3,00    4,00    3,00
3,00    0,00    0,00
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you

```
Solution thx @EdChum = 
df.loc[df['max'].shift(+ 2) == 0,'true'] = 0
```

Comment: you mean `df.loc[df['max'].shift(- 2) == 0,'true'] = 0`

Comment: @EdChum, what I actually meant was `df.loc[df['max'].shift(+ 2) == 0,'true'] = 0` , but it works thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) with parameter `periods = 2`:

```
 df.loc[df['max'].shift(periods = 2) == 0,'true'] = 0
print df
   max  value  true
0    0      3     0
1    0      4     0
2    0      4     0
3    0      2     0
4    3      3     0
5    3      1     0
6    3      4     3
7    3      1     1
8    3      4     3
9    3      0     0
```